# porque mi formulario php no envia el mail?

Tags: php, html

tengo un problema que es que tengo un formulario php creado y guardado ya en una pagina web
cuando lo uso anda todo correcto pero al momento de mandar el mail no me llega a mi mail o no se envía
este es mi código de php:

```
<?php
$destino = 'poppush7@gmail.com';
$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$mensaje = $_POST['message'];
$info = "Haz recibido un nuevo mensaje. \n nombre: $nombre \n mail: $mail \n numero: $numero \n mensaje: $mensaje";
echo $info;
mail($info,"Contacto web", $continido);
?>
```

utilice el echo $info para saber si se estaban guardando los post

Comment: Tal vez le hagan falta headers, por favor lee [esto](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp) e intenta de nuevo.

Comment: Será que se están yendo a spam? Tiene pinta de enviarse sin los encabezados necesarios para evitarlo

Answer (score 0):

ya lo logre hacer el problema estaba en que no manda mails a Gmail (aun no se porque) una vez cambiado el mail se manda sin ningún problema
adjunto el código para alguna persona que necesite

```
<?php
$destino = "charquito@charquito.site";
$nombre = $_POST["name"];
$mail = $_POST["email"];
$numero = $_POST["numero"];
$mensaje = $_POST["message"];

$headers =  'From: franco <charquito@charquito.site>' . "\r \n" .
            'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r \n" .
            'X-maile: PHP/' . phpversion();

$continido = "Nombre: " . $nombre . "\n Mail: " . $mail . "\n Numero: " . $numero . "\n Mensaje: " . $mensaje;
mail($destino,"Contacto web",$continido,$headers);
header("Location:gracias.html");
```

?>